# $Host.UI.Prompt() is ignoring the attribute 'DefaultValue' in FieldDescription

Tags: powershell, input

I am trying to get user input, and return a default value if no input was given.

I am going with `$Host.UI.Prompt`, since according to MSDN ( [PSHostUserInterface.Prompt Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.host.pshostuserinterface.prompt%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) ) it should provide exactly this functionality - or so I thought.

In short: `$Host.UI.Prompt` method accepts a collection of `FieldDescription` objects. each of those objects can be assigned with a `DefaultValue` attribute, which is supposed to be returned when no input is given by the user for this specific field.

I've got everything working as desired, except the default value part.

To see if  messed up my script, i also tried with example scripts from the internet, like [this](http://poshcode.org/608) one:

`$Host.UI.PromptForChoice` works fine, the value from DefaultChoice is returned as expected when I make no choice.

`$Host.UI.Prompt` won't provide the assigned `DefaultValue`s as expected. like, the default value is not shown on the prompt, and when I hit enter without any input given, I get empty/zero results.

Interestingly enough, when I run this exact script in PowerGUI, the GUI popup shows all the assigned DefaultValues proposed in the according inputfield.
So it seems to work, just that the `$Host.UI` object in PowerShell appears to be bugged in a way...

I know that I can easily workaround this, but I don't want to.
I want to understand why it is *not* doing what it's *not* doing, just because.

I am running on Windows 7 Professional 64bit, with all the latest updates.

here is my PSVersionTable:

```
Name                           Value                                                                                                                                     
----                           -----                                                                                                                                     
PSVersion                      4.0                                                                                                                                       
WSManStackVersion              3.0                                                                                                                                       
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1                                                                                                                                   
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.18444                                                                                                                           
BuildVersion                   6.3.9600.16406                                                                                                                            
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0}                                                                                                                      
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.2
```

i hope someone else here, preferably with the same setup, can try to verify & reproduce this behaviour!

thanks in advance!

Comment: If it helps i have psVersion 3.0 and same OS and i get similar results. I tried in ISE and shell.

Comment: thanks, so it appears we do have a bug here ... where would be the best place to report this to microsoft? (if there even is such a place)